# How to make the for loop faster when comparing gridview rows with database?

Tags: sql, vb.net, for-loop, gridview, dataset

I am fetching a record set of 40k plus records. The requirement is to highlight the records that exists or doesn't exist in our database in a table.

So what we had done is to pick every record and compare with the database table using a procedure.

```
If exists(Select FunctionalLocation from EngineeringData where
                 FunctionalLocation = @Asset_Number 
)
Begin
                 Select 1
End

                 Else
Begin                

                 Select 0
End


END
```

but this is taking so much time and sometimes timeout.

Is there any way we can optimize this code?

```vb
For k = 0 To gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.Rows.Count - 1

    If k < 50000 Then    ' to test only

        Dim row = gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.Rows(k)

        Dim RowEffect As Integer
        Dim dSetReturn As New DataSet
        ParamValue(0) = row.Cells(1).Text
        ParamValue(1) = row.Cells(4).Text
        dSetReturn = Func.SP_ReturnDataset(con, "[dbo].[USP_Check_FunctionalLocations]", True, ParamName, ParamType, ParamValue)
        RowEffect = dSetReturn.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
        Dim gRow As GridViewRow = gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.Rows(k)
        Dim cBox As CheckBox = CType(gRow.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox)

        If RowEffect = 0 Then
            'dtFL.Rows(k).Cells("Status").Value = True
            'dtFL.Rows(k).ReadOnly = True
            gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.Rows(k).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Tomato
            cBox.Checked = True

        Else

            gv_InfoFunctionalLocation.Rows(k).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen
            cBox.Checked = False

        End If

        If cBox.Checked = True Then
            btnImportFL.Enabled = True
            btnImportFL.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Navy
        End If
    End If

Next
```

Is there quick fix since we are short on time and resources?

Comment: I've doen this sort of thing by turning the list I want into an XML string and passing as a single string, or multiple strings if a single one is too long. Then join in sql.

Answer (score 0):

If the data set in the db is considerably larger than 40k, bulk  load the data's ID values into the db (temp table) and then inner join it, to download only the set of IDs already in the db. Download the results of the query into a HashSet

Otherwise if the db data set isn't orders of magnitude larger than 40k, just download every ID in the db and load them into a HashSet,

In either case you now can iterate the data asking the hashset if the ID is present